# Camera permission dialogue box not appearing

Tags: javascript, python, html, opencv, flask

So I've been trying to make a UI in which the user can upload his pictures to local system (To move from one location to images database by opening a file manager dialogue box) or take live pictures and add to the images database. I made this simple html file which is running well but after i try to run it with flask after creating a localhost , google chrome doesn't prompt for camera permission from above and somehow the permission is already granted but the camera doesn't work . Here is the code- app.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")


@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
#for the intake of the folder name that needs to be created or selected in the dataset folder
def upload():
    fold_nam=request.form["name"] 


    folder_name = request.form.get('superhero')
    '''
    # this is to verify that folder to upload to exists.
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'files/{}'.format(folder_name))):
        print("folder exist")
    '''
    #Change this target variable as per the device working in (set your own path address of the dataset folder)
    target="/home" + str(fold_nam).lower()
    print(target)
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)
    print(request.files.getlist("file"))
    for upload in request.files.getlist("file"):
        print(upload)
        print("{} is the file name".format(upload.filename))
        filename = upload.filename
        # This is to verify files are supported
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if (ext == ".jpg") or (ext == ".png"):
            print("File supported moving on...")
        else:
            render_template("Error.html", message="Files uploaded are not supported...")
        destination  = "/".join([target, filename])
        print("Accept incoming file:", filename)
        print("Save it to:", destination)
        upload.save(destination)

    # return send_from_directory("images", filename, as_attachment=True)
    return render_template("complete.html", image_name=filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

    <form id="frm1" action="/action_page.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>


        <input type="file" id="real-file" hidden="hidden" />
        <button type="button" id="custom-button">CHOOSE A FILE</button>
        <span id="custom-text">No file chosen, yet.</span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
            const customBtn = document.getElementById("custom-button");
            const customTxt = document.getElementById("custom-text");

            customBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                realFileBtn.click();
            });

            realFileBtn.addEventListener("change", function () {
                if (realFileBtn.value) {
                    customTxt.innerHTML = realFileBtn.value.match(
                        /[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/
                    )[1];
                } else {
                    customTxt.innerHTML = "No file chosen, yet.";
                }
            });

        </script>
    </form>


    <div class="container">
        <video id="video" width="300" height="300" autoplay="true"></video>
        <button class="button" id="snap">Photo</button>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
        <br>

        <a id="download" href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>download</a>
        <div>

            <input type="submit" value="Upload!" id="upload-button"><br>

</body>
<script>



    $("#file-picker").change(function () {

        var input = document.getElementById('file-picker');

        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length;i++) {
            //koala.jpg, koala.JPG substring(index) lastIndexOf('a') koala.1.jpg
            var ext = input.files[i].name.substring(input.files[i].name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()

        if((ext == 'jpg') || (ext == 'png')) {
            $("#msg").text("Files are supported")
        }
        else {
            $("#msg").text("Files are NOT supported")
            document.getElementById("file-picker").value = "";
        }

    }


});

</script>


<script src="./index.js"></script>

</html>
```

index.js

```
(() => {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = document.getElementById("img")
    var download = document.getElementById("download")


    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then((stream) => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        });
    }
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", () => {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 300, 300);
        img.setAttribute("src", canvas.toDataURL("image/png"))
        download.setAttribute("href", canvas.toDataURL("image/png"))
    });
})()
```

All i want is to run the **index.html ** using flask with the camera running properly in localhost.

I know that my code is not in the finished state , but i'm stuck at this very place. I would like to mention that all my files are in proper directories and i have no indentation errors etc. Anyone who is willing to help is requested to mention every minute detail as I'm not very good at this .
Thankyou!